# Magento multisite - bulk enable and set visibility differently per site

Tags: php, mysql, magento

We have a multi-store magento setup, and we have several stores under the main site.  We need to both enable and set search visibility for several hundred products, but we don't want those products to just show in every store, in fact, we only want them to show in one store.  I have tried updating the Magento database, only to find out that not every store has a set of attributes to update, which would require some fancy SQL to perform.  I have also tried creating an Excel XML import, which did not work.  The import file looks like this (I tried it 2 ways):

```
sku visibility  status  _store
112001          4   1   otherstore
11924-01    4   1   otherstore

sku visibility  status  _store
112001          4   1   otherstore
112001          1   2   admin
11924-01    4   1   otherstore
11924-01    1   2   admin
```

Both ways appeared to just reset the status completely, as in nothing in the status field.  I am a little wary of doing this via PHP since I am not well versed in Magento and have heard un-great things about mucking about in the core files, but at this point if it will work I'll do anything.  I can't help but think that someone has done this before, via plugin on SQL or PHP, so any help here is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Backup your database.  Do a product export of the products this applies to. Edit the csv file to show the correct store for all of those products.  In magento delete all of the products this applies to.  Now import the csv that you previously exported and edited.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I needed something a bit more robust then that, this will be an ongoing thing.  I found, and have sucessfully used, Magmi.  thank you for the help though.

Answer (score 0):

I found, and sucessfully used, [Magmi](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/magmi/index.php?title=Main_Page).  Was incredibly fast, and seemed to do the job well.  The documentation isn't great, but it's usable.